# call Symfony events only in certain cases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my project i manage users, and **both username and password are mandatory** (because i use FOSUserBundle) and i can handle them in two ways :

- If the user should have access to the admin area, the username and password should be set by the user registering (eg : myusername / mYpAsSwOrD)
- If the user should not have access to the admin area, this username and password are defined by default (eg user123, pass123 where 123 is the userID)

I'm not completely at ease with the subtelties of eventListener/ dispatcher in symfony.

In order to have such a behavior i have created a listener :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

use MyBundle\Entity\User;

class UserListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity     = $args->getEntity();
        $em         = $args->getEntityManager();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $entity->setUsername('user'.$entity->getId());
            $entity->setPassword('user'.$entity->getId());
            $entity->setEmail('user'.$entity->getId());

            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

with a service :

```
mybundle.user_listener:
    class: MyBundle\EventListener\UserListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
```

But this obiously doesn't work : since this is a service, it applies everytime i add of update a user.

My question is : 
**how can i apply this listener only when i need it : ?**

- only on insert (not on update)
- only if in the controller "i ask for it"

=> **Maybe i'm wrong but i can't pass parameter from a controller to a postPersist Event?**

Comment: check the unitofwork,   to see what the changeset is, determine wether or not to run the code..

Comment: So in that case, i would not use any listener ?

Comment: yes you would,   but inside this listener,   you can check, exactly what has changed in your user entity,   and only run the setters, and persist and flush,   IF anything relevant has changed ..         or am i misunderstanding the question ?

Comment: it isn't what has changed in my entity that matters, it is in which condition this persist happens (not related to the User entity) i want to change this username/password only in certain condition . But i've no idea how to pass parameters in such a listener : to keep it simple : how to run this postPersist only if `$isRegularUser == true`. Do you have any link or example that i can look at ? Thanks

Comment: is isRegularUser a property on user ?   if so just check (if $entity->isRegularUser == true) {}      

if it is not a property,   can this be derived from any other user properties maybe ?    i would assme that   isRegularuser   depends on some of the properties in user ...

Comment: You probably don't want to be using doctrine events for this sort of business logic.  Seems like you could implement this right in the controller but if not, use the Symfony event system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is don't use this type of logic for this case in a listener, is a particular case and latter may be confused when try to create a user in other place.

Can implement this logic in your controller or repository, example:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function saveUser(User $user, $autoGenerated = false)
    {
        $this->_em->beginTransaction();

        if ($autoGenerated) {
            $user->setUsername('user'.time());
            $user->setPlainPassword('user'.time());
            $user->setEmail('user'.time().'@example.com');
        }
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush($user);

        $this->_em->refresh($user);

        if ($autoGenerated) {
            $user->setUsername('user'.$user->getId());
            $user->setPlainPassword('user'.$user->getId());
            $user->setEmail('user'.$user->getId().'@example.com');
        }

        $this->_em->flush($user);

        $this->_em->commit();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Firstly the user is saved with a random name, and updated with the real id in other flush. This logic is executed in a transaction to avoid users with a random name if the second flush fails.